# HTML5 Video: Fire play at specific video time

Tags: javascript, html, video

Is there a better way / practice to get the same results as my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8dsco0o3/), and possibly avoid that 1 second lag when `play();` is fired.
I don't need the entire video to `loop`, but to restart at a specific point in the video's timeline.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/8dsco0o3/

## Repeat video to a specific time:

HTML:

```
  <video id="myVideo" width="720" height="476" autoplay>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

JavaScript:

```
  var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
  vid.onended = function() {
    vid.currentTime = 3;
    vid.play();
  };
```